# Phone Gap Build with Google Chrome Packaged Apps

Tags: cordova, dart, google-chrome-app, phonegap-build, cordova-chrome-app

Does anyone know of any instructions, samples, videos, etc, about using Phone Gap Build with Google Chrome Packaged Apps?

Also, is there any reason to avoid programming mobile Chrome apps in Dart?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was at PhoneGap day US 2013 where they talked about this. Here is a link to the EU one.

http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/11/21/chrome-apps-pgdayeu/

Here is the Google Blog post:

http://blog.chromium.org/2014/01/run-chrome-apps-on-mobile-using-apache.html

Here is a link to the GitHub repo with a bunch of sample apps:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples#mobile-support